# How to change styling of an HTML tag

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am working on a project where i want to change the styling of a `<div>` using c# in asp.net
my html code is

```
 <div id="xyz" style="display: none" runat="server"> Please Register YourSelf First</div>
```

and my c# code is

```
 if (q == 0)
        {

            HtmlGenericControl ul = (HtmlGenericControl)(this.FindControl("xyz"));
            ul.Style["display"] = "block";
        } else { ...}
```

in which ul is always showing null..
please help

Comment: In which `asp.net lifecycle phase` are you calling the code? And is the code part of a `UserControl`?

Comment: `FindControl()` is not recursive, so `this` has to be the immediate parent of `xyz`. Note that you should be able to access `xyz` directly (it should be a protected field in the designer-generated portion of the class).

Comment: no i m not using any userControl . i am writing this code on button click

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `xyz.Attributes.Add("style", "display: block")` or `xyz.Attributes["style"] = "display: block"`.

***FYI:*** You do not need to use **FindControl** unless xyz is located inside Data controls like Repeater.

```
<div id="xyz" style="display: none" runat="server">
    Please Register YourSelf First
</div>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton"
    OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Submit" />

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xyz.Attributes.Add("style", "display: block");
}
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as ***Answer***. It'll help others who look for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Panel ID="foo" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Then in your code behind....

```
foo.Attributes.Add("style", "border: 1px solid");
```

Comment: Panel renders div tag to client browser. OP doesn't gain anything by replacing div with Panel, unless you use some features of Panel like *DefaultButton*.